# How does delay work on the stm32l152RC?

Tags: c, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I just bought an stm32l152RC and was wondering how the delay works.
The system clock is 16Mhz.

Code:

```
static volatile uint32_t TimingDelay;
void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount);


int main(void) {
    Config_Systick();
    char *RCCp = (char*) 0x40023800;
    int *PBp = (int *) 0x40020400;
    // RCC Config
    *((int*) (RCCp + 28)) |= 0x3f;
    *((int*) (RCCp + 32)) |= 1;
    *PBp = 0x5000;

    while (1) {
        GPIO_TOGGLE(GPIOB, LD_GREEN); //toggle green led
        Delay(1000); // 1 second?
    }
} // end of main

    RCC_ClocksTypeDef RCC_Clocks;
    void Config_Systick() {
        RCC_GetClocksFreq(&RCC_Clocks);
        SysTick_Config(RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency / 1000); // setting changed to / 1000
    }

    void TimingDelay_Decrement(void) {
        if (TimingDelay != 0x00) {
            TimingDelay--;
        }
    }

    void Delay(uint32_t nTime) {
        TimingDelay = nTime;
        while (TimingDelay != 0) {
        };
    }
```

When I execute `Delay(1000);` in this case the Delay is 1 second, could someone please explain why the delay is 1 second?

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for your answer, I actually did read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research this is the answer I came up with.
doing `SysTick_Config(RCC_Clocks.HCLK_Frequency / 1000);` means you'r setting 1000 ticks per second. when you do `Delay(100)` the delay will be 100 ms.